# Remote Debugging using Visual Studio - How to overcome a firewall blocking port 135

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tcp, remote-debugging

.Net remote debugging using VS requires port 135 (DCOM) to be opened.

Is it possible to change it to another port?
Is it possible to tunnel through another port by running bridge on the remote server?

Thanks
Saar

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating a VPN connection between the server and debugger machine.

Saar